# Boost C++ and Android 3

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

I tried to google and SO search. So far I was able to find only conflicting information. If it is too hard to marry Boost and Android, maybe there are replacements? I am especially interested in smart_ptr, threads, function, lexical_cast, string_algo and containers. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why would it be too hard to marry Boost and Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this project: https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android

> Boost for android is a set of tools to compile the main part of the
>   Boost C++ Libraries for the Android platform.
>
> To compile Boost for Android you may use the customized NDK r4b
>   provided by [Dmitry Moskalchuk aka CrystaX](http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk.php). Or you may download
>   official [NDK r5c](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Since it was written NDK r6 have been released by Google (and customized by CrystaX). Thus I suggest you to build "Boost for Android" against the latest NDK r6 from CrystaX, as described on its site:

---

`./build-android.sh crystax/ndk/root`

This command will download and build boost against the Crystax NDK and output the final header and libs and in the build folder.

Now that you got boost compiled you must add it to your `Android.mk` file. First copy the the `include` and `lib` folder over to your `jni` folder. I copied it just into: `/jni/boost/`.

Add the following to your `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/include/ 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/external/boost/lib/ -lboost_system -lboost_...

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
```

Comment: Is there boost build scripts for latest android ndk(r8)?

Comment: @6opuc Not that I'm aware of. I guess you'll have to wait for CrystaX' version of NDK r8, or post a request on his bugtracker. (See also: http://www.crystax.net/trac/ndk/ticket/6).