# Is Boost C++ thread supported by both iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, boost

I'm trying to write some multithreading code for mobile apps. I'm thinking about Boost C++ thread library for both iOS and Android. But anyone knows if Boost thread is supported by both platforms? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I'm currently maintaining `boost::thread` code that runs on iOS and Android.

That said, unless you're attempting to run the same codebase on the two platforms, I would recommend [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) on iOS instead of `boost::thread`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Besides thread library, are all other libraries supported by both iOS and Android? I really want to use all good features in Boost library.

Comment: Yes, I've been able to leverage many of the boost libraries successfully. I haven't run into a library that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I think these posts may help you:

[Boost C++ and Android 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711029/boost-c-and-android-3)

[C++ Boost on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361751/c-boost-on-iphone)

Sounds like it's possible on both Android and IOS

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look at those links.