# Common framework for Linux and IOS

Tags: ios, linux

Is there a common framework which can be used for all system APIs that works in both linux and IOS?

Edit - "System API" means all file related operations, inter-process , threads , network related operations.

Comment: What do you mean by "all system APIs"?

Comment: I don't understand, but I am guessing the answer is "no"

Comment: they are both posix systems..

Comment: You're looking for a library/framework that targets both linux and iOS? What sort of things do you want the library to do? Apparently Qt runs on iOS now.

Comment: @justin - It means that the same POSIX API will work in IOS also . Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The new C++11 includes a new threading model with native support for threaded computation. You can also take a look at boost::thread, there are ports to many other [unofficially supported platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284382/is-boost-c-thread-supported-by-both-ios-and-android) like iOS.